# how to convert the a string to a calendar object in java

Tags: java, calendar

I have the below string which is input to my method
String xymessage="Your item(s) will be ready Today for pickup by 10:00 a.m.        ";

Now how can i convert this string to a calendar object.

I was able to extract the day ie. whether its "today" or "tomorrow". And also the time ie. "10:00 a.m."
using these two parameters as input ie. today and 10:00 a.m. will it be possible for me to convert it to a calendar object?
Sample code snippet:

```
String xymessage="Your item(s) will be ready Today for pickup by 10:00 a.m.        ";
if(null != xyMessage){
    //removing empty spaces.
    xyMessage=xyMessage.trim();
    LOGGER.debug("sellerId:"+delivSeller.getSellerId()+" and xymessage:"+xyMessage);
    if(xyMessage.contains("Today")){
        //this means its today
        String[] xyArray = xyMessage.split("pickup by");
        if(xyArray.length == 2){
            String timeVal=xyArray[1];
        }
    }else{
        //this means its tomorrow
    }  
}
```

Comment: How will you handle scenarios like: "Your item(s) will be ready for pickup the day after tomorrow at 10:00 a.m.";

Comment: @NeilA, Didn't understand your question. can you pls elaborate.?

Comment: As suggested by Uba, the Calender has methods to set/get/add(or inversely subtract) from the calendar.
What my comment was referring to was the format of the string...
Where does this string come from ie: System Generated, User Input...
If system generated then why not just send the pickup date and time through to this code, that way you only need to use the SimpleDateFormat.
If user input then how are you going to handle all scenarios and possible message formats, in this case I would rather have the user specify the date(and time) and have your code generate the message from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()` to get a calendar object with the current date and time. Using the [add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29), [get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29), and [set()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int%29) methods, you can set the calendar object correctly. For instance, to change the date to tomorrow's, you could do: `cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);`

To set the hour, `cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, hr);` where hr was initialized with the hour to be set. Similarly for minutes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat for the format you want. But as you are having a.m. or p.m. instead of plain simple AM/PM, it makes a bit of complication.
Check the below code if it helps for "today" condition :
Here variable 'time' is what you have extracted like "10:00 a.m."

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date date = new Date();
    String timeArray[]=time.split(" ");
    String minArray[]=timeArray[0].split(":");
    date.setHours(Integer.parseInt(minArray[0]));
    date.setMinutes(Integer.parseInt(minArray[1]));
    if(!timeArray[1].startsWith("a")){
        date.setHours(date.getHours()+12);
    }
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
    SimpleDateFormat finalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aa");
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar tomorrow = Calendar.getInstance();
    tomorrow.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    String xyMessage = "Your item(s) will be ready Today for pickup by 10:00 a.m.        ";
    if (null != xyMessage) {
      //removing empty spaces.
      xyMessage = xyMessage.trim();
      if (xyMessage.contains("Today")) {
        //this means its today
        String[] xyArray = xyMessage.split("pickup by ");
        String time = xyArray[1].replace(".", "");

        today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sdf.parse(time).getHours());
        System.out.println("calendar:" + finalFormat.format(today.getTime()));

      } else {
        //this means its tomorrow
        String[] xyArray = xyMessage.split("pickup by ");
        String time = xyArray[1].replace(".", "");

        tomorrow.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sdf.parse(time).getHours());
        System.out.println("calendar:" + finalFormat.format(tomorrow.getTime()));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

just use SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa")

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
    String val = "10:00 a.m";
    val = val.replace(".", "");

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    Calendar temp = Calendar.getInstance();
    temp.setTime(dateFormat.parse(val));

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    if ("tomorrow".equalsIgnoreCase("YOUR_STRING")) {
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    }

    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, temp.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, temp.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

    System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + ":"
            + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + ":"
            + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
            + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
}
```